# Background music pauses after going to a new scene Swift 3 SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

On Swift 3 and SpriteKit, the music for the apple music app pauses every time I go to a new scene. Is there any way to continue running the music after going to a new scene?

Comment: It probably doesn't pause but rather stops because your player deallocates. Make the player global.

Comment: well by default the scene pauses when transitioning, it wouldn't deallloc till after the transition completes.  Create an `SKTransition` instance and set `pausesOutGoingScene` to false, and present your scene with this transition

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thank you, it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the scene pauses when transitioning.

Create an `SKTransition` instance and `pausesOutGoingScene` to `false`, and present your scene with this transition

```
func presentNewScene(incomingScene:SKScene)
{
    let transition = SKTransition()
    transition.pausesOutGoingScene = false
    self.view!.presentScene(incomingScene,transition:transition)
}
```